# Attach a custom syntax checker to my custom-made DSL file?

Tags: parsing, intellij-idea, ide, dsl

I use a simple format to describe some rules in the app, it's a text file with some structure which is nor JS, neither HTML or anything else.

I have created a utility that can parse and check the syntax of this file and return a report, like JSLint, ESLint or other similar tools.

Now, is it possible to somehow connect the utility to WebStorm without having to write a dedicated plugin so that to highlight the issues in the file in real-time, like how I would do with linters?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. All linters integrated into WebStorm have special code running in the IDE to invoke the linters and show results in real time.